# VB: Populating datagridview with individual sql queries

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've been stuck for roughly 8 hours on this problem and it just keeps looking bleaker and bleaker.

I am writing POS software and I want to use a datagridview to display each individual item that's been checked out.  When the program is executed, the datagridview displays the first checked out item, but when another item gets checked out, it merely overwrites the current row.

Unfortunately, every time I even attempt to get VB to add a new row, I get a very specific error:

Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to rectify this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use data binding, or add the row to the data source that you are binding to.

Comment: What is the data source bound to, a DataTable?  If so, add the row to the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually worked it out.  I don't want databinding so I decided to use a streamreader to write to a variable.  I then defined the datagridview's colums and made it add the contents of each variable to the datagridview. After this is done, a new line is added for each loop performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try Adding the new data to the datasource or databinding that the datagridview is bound to.. instead of adding the data to the datagrid